# Difference between media link from firebasestorage.googleapis.com and storage.googleapis?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I need to **upload images to Firebase Storage and get a download URL to use** as the `src` for the `<img src=""/>` tags in my web app.

When I upload an image to my bucket **from the browser** using the `firebase` client SDK, this is what I do:

```
const fileName = "someImage.jpg";
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('my-images/' + fileName);
const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file,metadata);    // I GET THE FILE FROM AN <input type="file"/>
```

And this is **how I get the downloadURL** to the recently uploaded file:

`const downloadURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();`

And I get a **download URL that looks like this:**

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/my-images%2FsomeImage.jpg?alt=media`

---

Now I'm **uploading an image through an Node script using the** `firebase-admin`, and this is what I'm doing:

```
async function uploadImage() {
  const filePath = "./src/assets/someImage.jpg";
  const fileName = "someImage.jpg";
  const options = {
    destination: '/my-images/' + fileName,
    public: true,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: 'public,max-age=86400,must-revalidate'
    }
  };
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    admin.storage().bucket().upload(filePath,options)      // <------ UPLOAD THE IMAGE
    .then((file) => resolve(file))
    .catch((err) => reject(err));
  });
}

uploadImage()
.then((file) => console.log(file))        // <---- THIS LOGS THE RESPONSE
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

This is the **response that it's logged in** the `.then()` clause:

There are other logs, but this is the important part:

```
File {
    metadata: {
      kind: 'storage#object',
      id: 'my-project.appspot.com/my-images/someImage.jpg/1576651561918519',
      selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/my-images%2FsomeImage.jpg',
      name: 'my-images/someImage.jpg',
      bucket: 'my-project.appspot.com',
      generation: '1576651561918519',
      metageneration: '1',
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      storageClass: 'STANDARD',
      size: '8724',
      mediaLink: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/my-images%2FsomeImage.jpg?generation=157621651561918519&alt=media',
      cacheControl: 'public,max-age=86400,must-revalidate',
    },
```

I **get the downloadURL from** the `mediaLink` property:

`mediaLink: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/my-images%2FsomeImage.jpg?generation=157621651561918519&alt=media',`

I see that **both of these links work** as `src` for my `<img src="URL"/>` tags.

**OPTION A** (from **firebase client** SDK):

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/my-images%2FsomeImage.jpg?alt=media`

**OPTION B** (from **firebase-admin** SDK):

`https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/my-images%2FsomeImage.jpg?generation=157621651561918519&alt=media`

And I also notice that I can access the file I've uploaded with the `firebase-admin` by using the same `firebasestorage` API link that I get when I upload files from the browser. I just need to replace the filename, like:

`"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/my-images%2F" + "WHATEVER_FILE_NAME.jpg" + "?alt=media"`

---

**QUESTION**

What is the difference between the link from OPTION A (generated from an upload using the `firebase` SDK on the browser) and the link from OPTION B (generated from an upload using the `firebase-admin` SDK from a Node script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference the `firebase-admin` which is used in cloud function will give you a link with `storage` while if you use firebase from the client side then you will get a link with `firebasestorage`.

But both options will send the image to the same firebase storage,thats why you the image uploaded from firebase admin can be accessed also with `firebasestorage`

Comment: So I can use both API links interchangeably? Note: It's weird that the images uploaded from `firebase-admin` can't load an image preview in the Firebase Storage Console. All images uploaded with the `firebase` client SDK have normal previews in the Console. I've created a support ticket asking them about it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: In addition of the answer of @Peter Haddad this behaviour is normal since firebase uses GCP Cloud Storage Buckets

this is the domain for gcp storage www.googleapis.com/storage
and this is for firebase  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com

both point to the same bucket using different domain.

Comment: **The links are not functionally equivalent.** See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

**The links are not equivalent.** Download URLs are generated special by the Firebase client SDKs, and contain a special token that authorizes client downloads.  This token can be revoked in the Firebase console to prevent further access.  This type of URL does not have a 100% similar concept in Google Cloud Platform.  The most similar concept in GCP is [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), but signed URLs have a lot more capabilies.

Medialink URLs don't carry much documentation as far as I can see, so they are apparently just intended for public access to objects.  They can apparently call out a specific version of an object.  Firebase download URLs can't do this - they always access the latest version of the object.